# UTF-8 in anchors do not work in Safari

Tags: url, encoding, utf-8, safari, anchor

I have spent a few hours on trying to figure out why UTF-8 chars aren't working with anchors and i am basically out of ideas.

Following has been added to the HTML head: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

A curl shows that the document is clearly UTF-8:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Mon, 20 Oct 2014 18:13:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
```

When i look at the result of the link in Safari status bar, it is rendered as:

```
http://localhost:80/#Forv%C3rres
```

But it is obviously unclickable.

If i type it correctly in the address it finds the anchor without any problems:

```
http://localhost:80/#Forværres
```

Comment: Are you sure that the source document is really encoded in UTF-8?  Safari is rendering the URL-encoded form of the link in your status bar, which is not inherently wrong nor does it itself imply that the link is "unclickable."  It does appear that Safari thinks the anchor contains a character with (hexadecimal) code C3.  Unicode character U+00C3 is capital 'A' with tilde, whereas the character you seem to be looking for is U+00E6.  Before you blame Safari, you should check whether your page works in other browsers.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, all other browsers seems to be working. Its a consistent problem with Safari, hence i have tried all my iOS devices aswell.  I edit my documents with TextMate and as always its set to UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you put URLs with UTF-8 characters in your document like this:

```
http://localhost:80/#Forværres
```

Unfortunately, this is not a valid URL. Non-ASCII characters in URLs are not RFC-compliant even if some browsers support them. You have to percent-escape the encoded UTF-8 byte sequence like this:

```
http://localhost:80/#Forv%C3%A6rres
```

This is tedious if you're editing HTML files manually but it's the only way if you want to be strictly standards-compliant.